# Is there anyway to have flash textfields expand upwards?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

With actionscript2, is there anyway to expand make a text field expand upwards if more text was added then the current size could hold, rather than downwards? Data is loaded from XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, there is not. However, you could monitor for the text change event, look at the number of lines in the field, and adjust the Y property of the field respectively.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I was hoping that Flash would have this option built in, I guess not. I appreciate the response. I'll have to take your suggestion and work off of that. Thanks.

Comment: That's how I have always done it. Whenever the text property is assigned, update the position of the field. It's not so bad really. In the case of loading data from xml, I wouldn;t 'monitor' it; maybe have a setter function to apply the text and do the subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

Actionscript 2 is **very** old now. Nothing new and cool is being done there. If you could use Flex and ActionScript 3 instead, you can just anchor the field to the bottom of its container:

```
<s:Group height="200">

    <s:Label bottom="0" left="0" right="0" text="I'm stuck on the bottom!" /> 

</s:Group>
```

Comment: Peter, thanks for the reply. Yeah, unfortunately due to some work restrictions, I'm stuck on using ActionScript 2. :S